# Neo4j 2.3 and full-text search

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

In my Neo4j application I'm using full-text search based on legacy Lucene indexing.

Right now

```
GraphDatabaseSettings.node_auto_indexing
GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable
```

are marked as deprecated...

How to correctly use Lucene full-text search in Neo4j 2.3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfrotunately [Legacy Indexing](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing.html) is deprecated and there is no alternatives at this point.

I asked about plans on implementing such functionality in future. Answer (by @chris.graphaware):

> yeah, it is planned for 3.0 or 3.1. On the other hand, I tend to say that ES is made for search and do it very well, of course it adds an additional layer to  your stack and concerns for consistency, but yeah, everything has a price :simple_smile:

Basically options are:

- Follow Neo4j 3.0+ development and checkout features that are introduced here
- Explore possibility to integrate ElasticSearch as search engine into your application (i belive that guys from GraphAware can offer you something in this area).
- Keep calm and wait for any news. I think that Neo4j won't drop functionality, without providing alternatives.

Comment: Be assured that we don't remove that before having a proper alternative in place. We know that lots of users depend on legacy indexing.